# Why VS Code syntax highlighting colors so dull in Windows? How can I fix it?

Tags: visual-studio-code

For a long time I have been thought that I have a bad monitor.

That is why colors in VS Code have been so dull.

But now I have compared Ubuntu and Windows colors and I understand that this is a problem of VS Code on Windows.

Comparing on the attached screenshot.

Theme and font settings (size, weight) are the same

Is there a way to fix it and make VS Code colors more saturated on Windows?
[image]

Comment: Are both using the same VSCode theme, and the same _version_ of that theme? Part of the issue seems to be in different font antialiasing behaviors (Ubuntu's default font smoothing always looks "heavier" than the Windows default), but I suspect those are slightly different color schemes in general.

Comment: Theme is the same — Light Modern. Font is the same — JetBrains Mono

Comment: Colours are the same [except for brackets] Rendering is different; one is antialiasing much harder than the other. Tested in enlargements on Photoshop.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes, colors are the same. And I try to understand, why Windows render colors so badly

Comment: anti-alias settings - see https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNuDJ.jpg - idk how to adjust that on Win, sorry

Comment: The colors are actually not the same. Anti-aliasing certainly does also play a role, but this is most likely related to how color profiles are used (or not used). This can make a world of a difference.

Comment: @DanielB - considering how much smear is happening, I'd call them close enough for jazz - https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQ1hw.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNtCe.png